# Performing 2d numerical integration with Boost Cpp

Tags: quadrature, integration, c, libraries

I've been learning to use the numerical quadrature of the **Boost** library for **Cpp**. In the documentation, I've found [an example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/gauss_kronrod.html) for **1D Gauss-Kronrod Quadrature** using **Boost**.

```
#include <boost/math/quadrature/gauss_kronrod.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

using namespace boost::math::quadrature;

auto f1 = [](double t) { return std::exp(-t*t / 2); };

double error;
double Q = gauss_kronrod<double, 61>::integrate(f1, 0, std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), 5, 1e-14, &error);
std::cout << Q << " " << error<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This calculates the integral

$$
Q = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^2}  dt
$$

up to some tolerance **1e-14** and with max depth **5**.
I'm trying to build upon this and calculate a double integral (cubature) like this

$$
Q = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(t^2+ s^2+ts)}  dt\ ds
$$

I've been trying to calculate this double integral using two 1d integrals. I tried to
look up if there is any double integtal function, but found none, so this is what I've tried so far

```
#include <boost/math/quadrature/gauss_kronrod.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

using namespace boost::math::quadrature;

auto f1 = [](double t, double s) { return std::exp(-(t*t+s*s+t*s) / 2); };

double error;
double Q = gauss_kronrod<double, 15>::integrate(gauss_kronrod<double, 61>::integrate(f1, 0, std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), 5), 0, std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), 5, 1e-9, &error);
std::cout << Q << " " << error<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I've introduced an integral of 2 variables. Two 1d quadrature functions are nested. But this gives compilation error.
**What am I doing wrong and is there any other cleaner way of doing 2d-numerical integrations?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you didn't find 2D quadrature is that we haven't implemented it yet. As to your compilation failure, this does the trick:

```cpp
#include <boost/math/quadrature/gauss_kronrod.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::math::quadrature;

    auto f1 = [](double t, double s) { return std::exp(-(t*t+s*s+t*s) / 2); };
    auto f = [&](double t) {
        auto g = [&](double s) {
            return f1(t, s);
        };
        return gauss_kronrod<double, 61>::integrate(g, 0, std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), 5);
    };

    double error;
    double Q = gauss_kronrod<double, 15>::integrate(f, 0, std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), 5, 1e-9, &error);
    std::cout << Q << ", error estimated at " << error <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That spits out 1.2092 for me.

Comment: This works fine and should work out for any convergent integral,  Thanks for your time. Will Boost implement cubatures in near future, do you have any information regarding this?

Comment: It's on the roadmap, but it's behind multivariate interpolation. Check out the Padua points which looks pretty easy to implement.